# Show New Page Table Detail From Page Table User Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, database, codeigniter-3

I use CodeIgniter for this project. In the first page of my project called "v_presensi_user_admin_awal", I have to show a table called "user". There are columns "no" for number, "Detail" for detail button, and "nama_user" for the name of a user. When I click the detail button, it should go to "v_presensi_user" for showing the detail presence of the user that I click. But it showed some errors.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'nama_user' of non-object

Filename: views/v_presensi_user.php

Line Number: 26

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/bolehstation/myreport/application/views/v_presensi_user.php
Line: 26
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/www/html/bolehstation/myreport/application/views/template.php
Line: 183
Function: view

File: /var/www/html/bolehstation/myreport/application/controllers/Presensi_user.php
Line: 33
Function: view

File: /var/www/html/bolehstation/myreport/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

And the following errors for other columns of detail.
First, the controller "Presensi_user" it shows "v_presensi_user_admin_awal" :

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['konten']="v_presensi_user_admin_awal";
        $this->load->model('presensi_m');
        $data['data_presensi']=$this->presensi_m->get_pres_user_adm_awal();
        $this->load->model('status_m');
        $data['data_status']=$this->status_m->get_status();
        $this->load->model('user_m');
        $data['data_user']=$this->user_m->get_user();
        $this->load->model('pengajar_m');
        $data['data_pengajar']=$this->pengajar_m->get_pengajar();
        $this->load->view('template', $data, FALSE);
    }
```

In the model "presensi_m" that get method "get_pres_user_adm_awal" :

```
public function get_pres_user_adm_awal()
  {
      $data_presensi= $this->db
        ->join('user','user.id_user=presensi.id_user')
        ->join('status','status.id_status=presensi.id_status')
        ->join('pengajar','pengajar.id_pengajar=presensi.id_pengajar')
        ->get('presensi')->result();
      return $data_presensi;
  }
```

In the "v_presensi_user_admin_awal" :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
   <tr>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>AKSI</th>
      <th>NAMA SISWA</th>
   </tr>
   <?php
     $no=0;
     foreach ($data_user as $usr) {
       $no++;
       echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$no.'</td>
         <td>'.anchor('Presensi_user/detail/'.$usr->id_user,'<div class="btn btn-info">Detail</div>').'</td>
         <td>'.$usr->nama_user.'</td>
       </tr>';
     }
   ?>
</table>
```

If I click the detail button, it should proceed the method called "detail" in the controller "Presensi_user" :

```
public function detail($id_presensi)
    {
        $this->load->model('presensi_m');
        $detail = $this->presensi_m->detail_data($id_presensi);
        $data['detail'] = $detail;
        $data['konten']="v_presensi_user";
        $this->load->view('template', $data, FALSE);
    }
```

The method called method "detail_data" in the model "presensi_m" :

```
public function detail_data($id_presensi = NULL)
  {
    $query = $this->db->where('id_presensi', $id_presensi)->get('presensi')->row();
    return $query;
  }
```

And finally it should appeared detail in view "v_presensi_user" :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>NO</th>
    <th>NAMA SISWA</th>
    <th>NAMA PENGAJAR</th>
    <th>HARI</th>
    <th>DATANG</th>
    <th>PULANG</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    $no=0;
    $no++;
    echo '<tr>
       <td>'.$no.'</td>
       <td>'.$detail->nama_user.'</td>
       <td>'.$detail->nama_pengajar.'</td>
       <td>'.$detail->hari.'</td>
       <td>'.$detail->datang.'</td>
       <td>'.$detail->pulang.'</td>
       <td>'.$detail->status.'</td>
    </tr>'
  ?>
</table>
```

Please help me to resolve this. I've tried and searched for many ways but can't find the correct way.

Comment: `var_dump($query)` in `detail_data` because it looks like the query doesn't giving back any rows. Guessing some problem with wrong id or some typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function detail_data($id_presensi = NULL)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('presensi');
    $this->db->where('id_presensi',$id_presensi);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }

    public function detail($id_presensi)
   {
      $this->load->model('presensi_m');
      $data['detail'] = $this->presensi_m->detail_data($id_presensi);
      $data['konten']="v_presensi_user";
      $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much... It solved!! Though your code is missing the join part, it's still giving me the idea about what to do. Thank youu..